# Any papers on use of convolution neural network for predicting price and hedagability when market making

Tags: research, papers

My idea:

CNN takes following input

```
Market Depth

My previous position price and position size when MM for current snapshot

Market book for past 10 to 30 snapshots
```

output:

```
Time taken to close both positions, long and short

Price change.
```

Are there any papers resembling my idea?

Comment: Do you have the training data for this?

Comment: @Attack68 yes, my client has agreed to test with current basic software he uses, and I will add code to log everything regarding order fullfillment and market book